# Computing conditional probabilities from three dimensional frequency table in R

Tags: r

I have a three dimensional frequency table. Let's say the three dimensions are `var1`, `var2` and `var3`. I would like to compute a new three dimensional table where each entry is the probability of `var1 = x` knowing that `var2 = y` and `var3 = z`. I could of course iterate through the table and compute the values, but I don't think that would be the "native" way to go in R.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for vectorization in data frames. It would help commentators if you provided example data and your function. Here's a toy example:

```
df <- bind_cols("var2" = 1:10, "var3" = 11:20)
```

I assume you are using some sort of probability function that depends upon "var2" and "var3" to calculate "var1".

```
df <- df %>% mutate(var1 = probability.fuction(var2, var3))
```